# What is the foolproof/proper way to set hostname and domain on CentOS

Tags: networking, centos, rhel

I've seen a few ways of changing hostnames of domain names.
One way is to issue the `hostname` command followed by the name such as:

```
hostname localhost.localdomain
```

`/etc/sysconfig/network` also has a `hostname` field, but changing that does not affect the output of the `hostname` command.

My question is, where is each of these used, which do I care about and why? What's the proper way of setting the hostname?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set your hostname in `/etc/sysconfig/network` then the system will automatically set your hostname for you every time you boot.

This magic is done in `/etc/rc.d/rc.sysinit`. It does this using the `hostname` command in the third line below:-

```
# Set the hostname.
update_boot_stage RChostname
action $"Setting hostname ${HOSTNAME}: " hostname ${HOSTNAME}
[ -n "${NISDOMAIN}" ] && domainname ${NISDOMAIN}
```

The variable `HOSTNAME` is defined in `/etc/sysconfig/network`.

If you set it manually using the `hostname` command, then it will not be persistent over a re-boot.

Comment: I actually don't have the rep to upvote this.... It sounds legit, though I'd like to confirm/ look into the /etc/rc.d/rc.sysinit script. Thanks a lot!